# How do i prove that $T(A_1)\geq T(A_2)$ iff $A_1$ is a subset of $A_2$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a non-void set and let $A$ be a subset of $X$. Denote $T(A)$ the topology on $X$ whose open sets are the null-set and the sets $O$ which contain $A$.
 show that

We have $T(A_1)\geq T(A_2)$ iff $A_1$ is a subset of $A_2$.

I am reading Point Set Topology by Steven A. Gaal, and this is the first question and I cant seem to find solutions to any of the problems anywhere, so I have no idea if I'm doing any of the exercises the right way. In the chapter to this problem the book says "$T_1\leq T_2$ and $T_2\geq T_1$ iff the family $O_1$ of open subsets associated with $T_1$ is a subfamily of the family $O_2$ belonging to $T_2$; $O_1$ is a subset of $O_2$"... but the book gives no proof of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that this is not precisely true as stated. Suppose $X=\{1\}$, $A_1=X$, and $A_2=\emptyset$. Then $A_1$ is not a subset of $A_2$, but $T(A_1)=T(A_2)=\{\emptyset, X\}$. So let us add the additional condition that $A\neq X$. (Alternatively, we could use the condition that $A\neq\emptyset$.)

Suppose that $A_1$ is a subset of $A_2$. Then every subset of $X$ which contains $A_2$ must also contain $A_1$. Thus each of the sets in $T(A_2)$ is also in $T(A_1)$ by definition, so $T(A_2)\leq T(A_1)$.

Now suppose instead that $T(A_2)\leq T(A_1)$. Since $A_2\in T(A_2)$, we also have $A_2\in T(A_1)$. So either $A_2$ is the empty set or $A_2$ contains $A_1$. If $A_2$ is the empty set and $A_1$ is not, then take $x\notin A_1$ (this is the only place we use our additional condition). Note that the set $\{x\}$ is in $T(A_2)$ but not $T(A_1)$. Thus we have a contradiction. So it must be that $A_1\subseteq A_2$.